# Anonymous controller in Minitest w/ Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, minitest

While converting from RSpec to Minitest I ran into a slight issue that Google has not helped with one bit, and that's figuring out how to do something like this:

```
describe ApplicationController do
  controller do
    def index
      render nothing: true
    end
  end

  it "should catch bad slugs" do
    get :index, slug: "bad%20slug"
    response.code.should eq("403")
  end
end
```

with Minitest.  Is there a way to create anonymous controllers like this inside of Minitest or is there documentation that could help me learn how to test controllers with minitest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think anonymous controllers are supported. Instead of using a DSL to create a controller, try defining a controller in your test.

```
class SlugTestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render nothing: true
  end
end

describe SlugTestController do
  it "should catch bad slugs" do
    get :index, slug: "bad%20slug"
    response.code.must_equal "403"
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it's not working. You should specify routes in the test as well

Comment: @oivoodoo If you use a non-existent route, you need to create a temporary route for your test case. This can be easily done with the `with_routing` method. [Here](http://pivotallabs.com/adding-routes-for-tests-specs-with-rails-3/) is a good example.

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like that:

```
# Add at runtime an action to ApplicationController
ApplicationController.class_eval do
  def any_action
    render :nothing
  end
end

# If disable_clear_and_finalize is set to true, Rails will not clear other routes when calling again the draw method. Look at the source code at: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionDispatch/Routing/RouteSet/draw
Rails.application.routes.disable_clear_and_finalize = true

# Create a new route for our new action
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'any_action' => 'application#any_action'
end

# Test
class ApplicationControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  should 'do something' do
    get :any_action

    assert 'something'
  end
end
```