# Minitest - test controller concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, minitest

I try to test my controller concerns using minitest-rails and combining this techniques:

http://ridingtheclutch.com/post/55701769414/testing-controller-concerns-in-rails.

[Anonymous controller in Minitest w/ Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832909/anonymous-controller-in-minitest-w-rails)

And i get "no route matches error":
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"fake"}

```
require "test_helper"
require "warden_mock"

class FakeController < ApplicationController
  attr_accessor :request

  def initialize(method_name=nil, &method_body)
    include MyConcern # method redirect_to_404 placed here

    @request = OpenStruct.new # mockup request
    @request.env = {}
    @request.env['warden'] = WardenMock.new # mockup warden

    if method_name and block_given? # dynamically define action for concern methods testing
      self.class.send(:define_method, method_name, method_body)
      test_routes = Proc.new do
        resources :fake
      end
      Rails.application.routes.eval_block(test_routes)
    end
  end
end


describe FakeController do # just very simple test
  context "just redirect_to_404" do
    it "it must redirect to /404" do
      @controller = FakeController.new(:index) { redirect_to_404 }
      get :index
      assert_redirected_to '/404'
    end
  end
end
```

I have rails 4.1.5 and minitest 5.4.0

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late for the OP, but I've done it in this way:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SolrSearchParamsFakeController < ApplicationController
  include SolrSearchParams # this is my controller's concern to test

  def index
    # The concern modify some of the parameters, so I'm saving them in a
    # variable for future test inspection, so YMMV here.
    @params = params
    render nothing: true
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Adding a route to the fake controller manually
  get 'index' => 'solr_search_params_fake#index'
end

class SolrSearchParamsFakeControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def test_index
    get :index, search: 'asdf wert'

    # finally checking if the parameters were modified as I expect
    params = assigns(:params)
    assert_equal params[:original_search], 'asdf wert'
  end
end
```

---

### Update

Sorry, but actually this is messing up all my tests that involve route access in some way, as with `Rails.application.routes.draw` I'm rewriting all the routes for tests and leaving just that `solr_search_params_fake#index` route.
Not sure how to add instead of rewriting.... a fix would be adding directly to `config/routes.rb` my test routes with an `if Rails.env.test?` condition? (yeah, it's a crappy solution, but I'll leave this here in case someone find a better way to do this).

Comment: You can set `Rails.application.routes.disable_clear_and_finalize = true` to prevent `draw` from rewriting all your routes. It will just append any new routes with that flag set