# How to DRY up controller tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I have dozens of controller tests that go to the tune of:

```
test "GET #show when not authenticated" do
  get :show, { id: 1 }
  assert_redirected_to '/login'
end
```

But my `application_controller` is locked down by default.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :ensure_logged_in
end
```

I should not have to add this test to every controller test. But I don't want to test one controller only.

How can I test that my application is locked down without littering my controller tests with this repetition?

Comment: Test it once when testing `ApplicationController`.

Comment: @BroiSatse but ApplicationController has no actions, or anything that renders views, nothing with a route.

Comment: RSpec allows you to create anonymous controller, define fake actions on it and test that it behaves as it should only because it inherit from another controller. Docs here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller

Comment: @BroiSatse I'm not using Rspec. I'm using the default Rails testing stack, which is minitest and some sugar. But the reasoning should stand either way. I'll try it.

Comment: Ah, missed that, sorry. This is one of the reason I prefer RSpec. I won't be able to help with MT. :( You can try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832909/anonymous-controller-in-minitest-w-rails

Comment: in RSpec Shared Examples can come in handy for drying these kind of things: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

Comment: Apart from the drying strategy @jethroo suggests, I'd still test that for every controller. Important enough and useful enough (prevention-wise).

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
test "Should redirect to login when user is not logged in"  do
    [:show, :edit, :new].each do |action|
      get action, {id: 1}
      assert_redirected_to '/login'
    end
end
```

And name this test like:

> test 'Redirected to login page when not authorized' do